# Trying to print out only the prime numbers into an output file

Tags: java, primes

I have to create an input file with a string of numbers in it. I need my program to create an output file with only the prime numbers of my input file in it. I'm totally lost as to how to create a loop to check my input file for prime numbers and create an output file with only prime numbers in it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class ClassWork5_3 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int line = inputFile.nextInt();


       while(inputFile.hasNext())
       {
         isPrime(line);

       }

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num)
    {
        boolean status;
        for(int i = 2; i < num/2; i++)
        {
            if (num%i==0)
            {
             status = false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you want to  read input numbers from console or file ?

Comment: I want the program to read numbers from the input file i created, then write the  prime numbers in their own output file.

Comment: Your approach is correct just you need to send the output to the file and you need to add if status returned is true then pw.write(line) something like that

Comment: and you forgot to add line=inputFile.nextInt() in while loop itself this is the main reason you are failing to get the result

Comment: I updated my code, but I can't figure out how to post it on here to look at. It's now still giving me all the same numbers in my output file as my input file, both prime and not prime.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method `isPrime()` is not correct.
This one should work, though it's probably not the most efficient one:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
  // Manage easy cases
  if (n <= 1)
    return (false);
  else if (n == 2)
    return (true);
  else if ((n % 2) == 0)
    return (false);

  // Check if (odd) number can be divided by something
  for (int i = 3; i <= n / 2; i += 2)
  {
    if ((num % i) == 0)
      return (false);
  }

  // If we get here, we got a prime number
  return (true);

} // isPrime
```

Then, your `while` loop should be something like this:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
  line = inputFile.nextInt();
  if (isPrime(line))
    pw.println(line);
}
```

Comment: You know `2` is a prime number but all other even numbers are not

Comment: @forpas Sorry, I inverted the check. Updated the answer

Comment: Don't forget to read the next line in the while loop. So you should add the statement "line = inputFile.nextInt"

Comment: @WalaSaif I entered the answer to quickly. Updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

This method iterates through the possible divisors of `n` up to `Math.sqrt(n)`:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    else if (n <= 3 )
        return true;

    boolean notPrime = true;

    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.sqrt(n); divisor++) {
        notPrime = (n % divisor == 0);
        if (notPrime)
            break;
    }

    return !notPrime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution using while loops and Math.sqrt():

```
public class X1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = null;
    Scanner fileInput = null;
    PrintStream fileOutput = null;

    try {
        inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        fileInput = new Scanner(inputFile, "UTF-8");
        fileOutput = new PrintStream("output.txt", "UTF-8");

        while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
            int number = fileInput.nextInt();
            if (isPrime(number))
                fileOutput.println(number);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        System.out.println("Unsupported encoding!");
    } finally {
        if (fileInput != null) {
            fileInput.close();
        }
        if (fileOutput != null) {
            fileOutput.close();
        }
    }

}

private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    int divider = 2;
    boolean prime = true;
    while (prime && (divider <= (int) Math.sqrt(n))) {
        if (n % divider == 0) {
            prime = false;
        }
        divider++;
    }
    return prime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code is for C++, but the algorithm is the same.

```
bool IsPrime(unsigned int num)
{
    // 2 is the first prime number; 
    if(num < 2) return false;

    // We check dividers up to the root of the given number,
    //because after that the multipliers are the same, but with switched places. 
    //Example: 12 = 1*12 = 2*6 = 3*4 = 4*3 = 6*2 = 12*1
    unsigned int limit = sqrt(num);

    //We calculated the limit outside the loop so it's calculated only once
    //instead of being calculated at every iteration of the loop.
    for(unsigned int i=2; i < limit; ++i)
    {
        //If we divide without a remainder, then it's not prime.
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }

    //We have tried with all the possible multipliers and have found no dividers.
    return true;
}
```